# Conditional Probability Concept Question

Tags: probability

The organizers of a cycling competition know that about 8% of the racers use steroids. They decided to employ a test that will help them identify steroid-users. The following is known about the test: When a person uses steroids, the person will test positive 96% of the time; on the other hand, when a person does not use steroids, the person will test positive only 9% of the time. The test seems reasonable enough to the organizers. The one last thing they want to find out is this: Suppose a cyclist does test positive, what is the probability that the cyclist is really a steroid-user.

S be the event that a randomly selected cyclist is a steroid-user and P be the event that a randomly selected cyclist tests positive.

***My questions is Can someone please translate and explain P(P|S) and P(S|P) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Pr(P|S)$ is the probability that the person tests positive, **given** that she uses steroids. We are told explicitly that this is $0.96$.

$\Pr(S|P)$ is the probability she is a steroid user, **given** that she tests positive. That is what we are asked to find.  Informally, if we confine attention to the people who test positive, $\Pr(S|P)$ measures the proportion of them that *really* are steroid users.

Since the problem says that the proportion of steroid users is not high (sure!), many of the positives will be **false** positives.  Thus I would expect that $\Pr(S|P)$ will not be very high: the test is not as good as it looks on first sight.

For computing, there are two ways I would suggest, the first very informal and probably not acceptable to your grader, and the second more formal.

$(1)$: Imagine $1000$ cyclists. About how many of them will test positive? About how many of **these** will be steroid users?  Divide the second number by the first, since $\Pr(S|P)$ asks us to confine attention to the subpopulation of people who tested positive.

$(2)$: Use the defining formula 
$$\Pr(S|P)=\frac{S\cap P}{\Pr(P)}.$$
The two numbers on the right are not hard to compute. I can give further help if they pose difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

We are given that $P(S)=0.08$ (hence $P(\neg S)=0.92$), $P(P|S)=0.96$ and $P(P|\neg S)=0.09$.
What we want to knwo is $P(S|P)$.

Note that $P(S\cap P)=P(S|P)\cdot P(P)$ as well as $P(S\cap P)=P(P|S)\cdot P(S)$, therefore
$$ P(S|P) = \frac{P(P|S)\cdot P(S)}{P(P)}.$$
Thus we first need $P(P)$, which we get from $P(P)=P(P|S)P(S)+P(P|\neg S)P(\neg S)$. At last now all is reduced to given values.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/08/understanding-bayesian-inference.html) is a relatively plain English explanation for Bayesian statistics.

Here, you have an evidence which says a user tested positive and the hypothesis you want to test against is whether steroids were used.

P(H | E) = P(E|H) x P(H) / [ P(E|H) x P(H) + P(E|~H) x P(~H) ]

from your numbers, P(H) = 8% so P(~H) = 92%, P(E|H) = 96% and P(E|~H) = 9%. Plug in all these numbers and you get ~ 48% which is quite low.